# does outlook 2016 for mac offer ability to customize snooze duration for calendar events/reminders?

Tags: macos, outlook, calendar, ms-office

trying to verify outlook features before upgrading office 2016 for mac

it seems office 2011 for mac and calendars on OS X Yosemite does't allow customized snooze for calendar entry and it takes more time to update reminder time for every entry if you are in the middle of something important whenever calendar reminder pops up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found answer to my question and wanted to share with community

[image: Outlook 2016 calendar snooze option on mac]